# Make a ball on a canvas slowly move towards the mouse

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

I am trying to make a ball move slowly towards my mouse.

Im using paper.js which is a simple animation library. Using this i have a ball moving on screen. These are some of the properties of the ball:

balls[0].vector.angle is its direction. 0 = right, 90 = down, 180 = left etc and everything in between

balls[0].point.x is its x position and .y for y position.

balls[0].vector.length is its speed.

I have put in a mouse move event and i think ive got the angle between them below:

```
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){

    var a = balls[0].point.y - e.clientY;
    var b = balls[0].point.x - e.clientX;
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(a, b) * 180 / Math.PI;
});
```

So i have made the ball stationary to test this and moved my mouse around it. To the left of the ball gives me 0 degrees. Above gives me 90. To the right gives me 180. And below the ball gives me -90 etc and everything in between.

I then calculated the distance in the same event and changed the speed to reflect the distance giving it a cap as max speed:

```
var distance = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );

var maxSpeed = 20; 
balls[0].vector.length = (distance/30 > maxSpeed) ? maxSpeed : distance/30;
```

So ive tested the speed and this and it works perfect. When i give the ball the angle from earlier its going in all sorts of directions. The speed still works, its just the ball is going in the wrong direction and im not sure what ive done wrong.

Comment: I'd recommend not to bother with angles.  Do a slope instead.  The problem with it going all over the place might be that you are getting an angle in degrees - by multiplying the atan * 180 and dividing by PI.  Then if you provide that as the angle for calculating movement, and the movement calculation does not convert it back to radians to plug into sin and cos, you will have really screwy movement.

Comment: ok i can look up slope and give this a try

Comment: slope is sort of working, its snapping into the oppersite direction when i go into the minus degrees and is flying away from me, I feel like its just 1 small equation im missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, you don't need trig functions. All you need is good old Pythagoras theorem.

```
var MAX_SPEED = 20;
var MIN_SPEED = 0.25; // Very slow if close but not frozen.
var ATTRACTION = 0.5; 
var diff_y = e.clientY - balls[0].point.y;
var diff_x = e.clientX - balls[0].point.x;
var distance = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y)
var speed = distance * ATTRACTION;
if (speed > MAX_SPEED) speed = MAX_SPEED;
if (speed < MIN_SPEED) speed = MIN_SPEED;
// The rates along axes are proportional to speed;
// we use ratios instead of sine / cosine.
balls[0].point.x += (diff_x / distance) * speed;
balls[0].point.y += (diff_y / distance) * speed;
```

Much more fun can be had by introducing forces and inertia.

Comment: Ive just tried this, ive made the balls new position the new_x and new_y and it instantly snaps to 0,0 or very close to, im not sure why.

Comment: Ah, got it; fixed.

Comment: Works great, couple of errors, you need to make the += at the bottom -= otherwise it zooms away from the mouse, and also sqrt throws and error so you have to put Math.sqrt

All fixed though, thankyou very much for your help :D

Comment: @RachelDockter A better way to fix that error would probably be to use `e.clientY - balls[0].point.y` and for x respectively. As that's where the actual mistake in the logic is

Answer (score 2):

Specify the direction in terms of deltas

```
var deltaX = e.clientX - balls[0].point.x;
var deltaY = e.clientY - balls[0].point.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);
var maxSpeed = 20; 
balls[0].vector.length = (distance/30 > maxSpeed ) ? maxSpeed  : distance / 30;
balls[0].point.x = balls[0].point.x + (balls[0].vector.length * deltaX / distance);
balls[0].point.y = balls[0].point.y + (balls[0].vector.length * deltaY / distance);
```

I think that will work

Comment: I just tried this an it sort of works if i move the mouse below the ball but as soon as i move it left or right or up it spasms everywhere :/